# Symfony2 fatal error FixturesBundle (cupón)

Tags: php, symfony2

Tengo un problema a la hora de instalar los `fixtures doctrine2` (desarrollo agil **Symfony2**). Agregué el require:

`"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"`

En el `composer.json`, después ejecuté composer update pero a la hora de  activar el bundle *DoctrineFixturesBundle* en el `app/Kernel.php`:

```
   $bundles = array(
         //..
         new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
         );
```

Me dice:

> "PHP fatal error: class 'Doctine\Bundle\DoctineFixturesBundle' 
>   not found in c:\xampp\htdocs\cupon\app\appKernel.php on line 26

¿Qué creen que esté pasando?, no he podido resolver el problema.

Comment: El appKernel.php declara un namespace al principio?

Comment: revisa el namespace y recuerda dar composer update a tu proyecto, el error aparece porque no encuentra el bundle que estás declarando

Comment: Que versión de Symfony estas utilizando? 2.....? Saludos.
(No puedo hacer comentarios por eso pregunto acá.)
Debido a que cuestionan mi comentario en una pregunta, aclaro, que la pregunta es porque en la Documentación Oficial de Symfony el Bundle tiene mantenimiento hasta la versión 2.2 de Symfony (bastante vieja)... verifica que este todo bien con la versión de Symfony que este utilizando. Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:

A. Lo agregas como

`$bundles = array(
 //.. 
new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(), );`

- Veo una coma suelta antes del último paréntesis.

B. El programa lo busca como es indicado en el mensaje de error:

> Doctine\Bundle\DoctineFixturesBundle

- Dice **Doctine** y no Doctrine. Puede haber un simple error ortográfico en tu código.

O bien :

C. Es muy posible que tu versión de Symphony necesite actualización y si no, que agregues como le exija la versión que tienes instalada.

Comment: La A no creo que sea, PHP admite `trailing comma` en la lista de elementos de un array.

Comment: Pero, ¿la coma sobrante tiene algún fin o utilidad en este caso? Si reparas un motor no conviene dejar tornillos sueltos. Aunque se pueda en teoría podría ser problemático.

Comment: No es comparable a un tornillo suelto. PHP simplemente lo permite (es como poner o no poner { } en un if de un solo estamento) En cualquier caso, no es causante de errores en ningún caso.